# Redirect a user to a page based on their username, when password is valid

Tags: php, redirect, authentication

I am trying to create a simple login system, without MySQL, just so that my clients can log in, and get directed to a page that will have information showing any links to files, and any meetings.

I have got this:

```
    //If the user is validated and every thing is alright, then grant the user access to the secured account page 
                //otherwise, display error message to the user
            if ($vpb_error == '')
            {
                if(isset($_SESSION['validfullname']) && isset($_SESSION['validusername']) && isset($_SESSION['validemail']) && isset($_SESSION['validpassword']))
                {
                    echo '<font style="font-size:0px;">completed</font>';
                }
                else
                {
                    echo '<div class="info">Sorry, it seems your information are incorrect and as a result, we are unable to create the required sessions to log you into your account. Please enter your valid account information to proceed. Thanks.</div>';
                }

            }
            else
            {
                echo $vpb_error;
            }
            fclose($vpb_databases);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<div class="info">Sorry, we could not get your valid username and password to process your login. Please try again or contact this website admin to report this error message if the problem persist. Thanks.</div>';
    }
}
//*********************************************************The login process ends here**********************************************************
```

How can I make it so that if everything is okay, it will then redirect them to  a page based on their username, ie if their username was james, they would be sent to james.php.

Cheers
Lewis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that the following if statement is the 'success' branch of code.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/768472/296555

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['validfullname']) && isset($_SESSION['validusername']) && isset($_SESSION['validemail']) && isset($_SESSION['validpassword']))
{
    header('Location: '.$_SESSION['validusername'] . '.php');
}
```

**EDIT**

You should really look at cleaning up your code; it's quite messy and looks overly complicated. You're mixing HTML and PHP, although not a show stopper, is generally frowned upon. This is where simple/easy-to-use frameworks come in. Even if you don't use them you should spend some time reading them because they do a lot things right and you'll learn more in a week than a lifetime of fumbling through it. Keep going... it's always fun to come back to code that you've written years ago and think, 'Man, I used to suck!'.

Ex.

```
<?php
// This looks like no error but then...
if ($vpb_error == '')
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['validfullname']) && isset($_SESSION['validusername']) && isset($_SESSION['validemail']) && isset($_SESSION['validpassword']))
    {
        // Mixing HTML directly in a script file
        echo '<font style="font-size:0px;">completed</font>';
    }
    // there is an error here.
    else
    {
        echo '<div class="info">Sorry, it seems your information are incorrect and as a result, we are unable to create the required sessions to log you into your account. Please enter your valid account information to proceed. Thanks.</div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

when the user is validated you can use php header() function.

header('Location: http://www.example.com/'.$_SESSION['username'].'.php');

Comment: Thanks,  So its just ` header('Location: '.$_SESSION['validusername'] . '.php');
`

Comment: $_SESSION['validusername'] that variable name sounds like its an boolean (true/false), if it contains the username you want, then yes.
Just as a side note: some older browser require an absolute URI not just the filename.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll want separate files for each user. Typically what I would do is once the user is proven to be authorized you redirect them to an authorized page which will then render the application data for your web-app.

This page will essentially be the same for everyone and you can use populate it with the data associated with that user. I am asumming you'd have a `links` table and a `meetings` table which would associate a `user_id` to a meeting/link. You could use a template engine or roll your own in PHP. Depending on how in depth your app starts to get you might want to look towards a template engine to render the HTML though.

Comment: That might be an easier approach, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Otherwise you'd have to pre-batch files for each user and would take up a bunch of memory/storage and that's not the point of having an n-tiered web app!